# Converting an array of 2 digit numbers into an integer (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, encryption, rsa

Is it possible to take an array filled with 2 digit numbers e.g.

```
[10,11,12,13,...]
```

and multiply each element in the list by 100^(position in the array) and sum the result so that:

```
mysteryFunction[10,11,12] //The function performs 10*100^0 + 11*100^1 + 12*100^3

= 121110
```

and also

```
mysteryFunction[10,11,12,13]

= 13121110
```

when I do not know the number of elements in the array?

(yes, the reverse of order is intended but not 100% necessary, and just in case you missed it the first time **the numbers will always be 2 digits**)

Just for a bit of background to the problem: this is to try to improve my attempt at an RSA encryption program, at the moment I am multiplying each member of the array by 100^(the position of the number) written out each time which means that each word which I use to encrypt must be a certain length.

For example to encrypt "ab" I have converted it to an array [10,11] but need to convert it to 1110 before I can put it through the RSA algorithm. I would need to adjust my code for if I then wanted to use a three letter word, again for a four letter word etc. which I'm sure you will agree is not ideal. My code is nothing like industry standard but I am happy to upload it should anyone want to see it (I have also already managed this in Haskell if anyone would like to see that). I thought that the background information was necessary just so that I don't get hundreds of downvotes from people thinking that I'm trying to trick them into doing homework for me. Thank you very much for any help, I really do appreciate it!

EDIT: Thank you for all of the answers! They perfectly answer the question that I asked but I am having problems incorporating them into my current program, if I post my code so far would you be able to help? When I tried to include the answer provided I got an error message (I can't vote up because I don't have enough reputation, sorry that I haven't accepted any answers yet).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

int returnVal (char x)
{
    return (int) x;
}

unsigned long long modExp(unsigned long long b, unsigned long long e, unsigned long long m)
{
unsigned long long remainder;
int x = 1;

while (e != 0)
{
remainder = e % 2;
e= e/2;

if (remainder == 1)
x = (x * b) % m;
b= (b * b) % m;
}
return x;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long p = 80001;
    unsigned long long q = 70021;
    int e = 7;
    unsigned long long n = p * q;
    std::string foo = "ab";
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); i++);

    {
        std::cout << modExp (returnVal((foo[0]) - 87) + returnVal (foo[1] -87) * 100, e, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: You tagged the question as C++ so please provide concrete C++ code for what you need. `mysteryFunction[10,11,12]` is not a C++ function. Replacing with `mysteryFunction(10,11,12)` means that the number of elements is known. Where are your data and in what format?

Comment: Sorry, I was using that as a pseudo code example of what I wanted, if I could provide concrete C++ format I wouldn't be asking the question. I'll make it more clear if I'm asking a question again. I don't fully understand your question at the end.

Comment: What is the error you get?  Your code is a bit different than what you had asked for... I only get a warning about unsigned/signed comparison in the `main`-loop.  Also, watch out, you might want to place curly braces after your `if(remainder==1)`.  And indent your code!

Comment: I have probably included it wrong, but I have tried `int main()
{
    unsigned long long p = 80001;
    unsigned long long q = 70021;
    int e = 7;
    unsigned long long n = p * q;
    std::string foo = "ab";
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); i++);

    {
        unsigned ar[] = {foo};
        std::cout << modExp (mysteryFunction(ar,2), e, n);
    }
}' and I get an error saying "error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'unsigned int' in installation.

Comment: @MichaelRad: But the code in your question is different; could you update that to show what exactly is giving you the error currently?  In your comment, you try to assign the string `foo` to an integer array which doesn't work.  You could either convert the string to an integer-array explicitly, or have `mysteryFunction` accept a string and do the conversion there.

Comment: How do I change `mysteryFunction` so that it accepts a string? Thanks again

Comment: @MichaelRad: I'll update my answer with a string-version. I assume the number of a character should be the ASCII value minus 87, is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelRad: Alright, check my answer again.  I hope this will work for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use plain C-style arrays, you will have to separately know the number of entries.  With this approach, your mysterious function might be defined like this:

```
unsigned mysteryFunction(unsigned numbers[], size_t n)
{
  unsigned result = 0;
  unsigned factor = 1;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    result += factor * numbers[i];
    factor *= 100;
  }

  return result;
}
```

You can test this code with the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unsigned ar[] = {10, 11, 12, 13};

  std::cout << mysteryFunction(ar, 4) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to utilize the STL's vector class, you won't separately need the size.  The code itself won't need too many changes.

Also note that the built-in integer types cannot handle very large numbers, so you might want to look into an arbitrary precision number library, like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

**EDIT:** Here's a version of the function which accepts a `std::string` and uses the characters' ASCII values minus 87 as the numbers:

```
unsigned mysteryFunction(const std::string& input)
{
  unsigned result = 0;
  unsigned factor = 1;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
  {
    result += factor * (input[i] - 87);
    factor *= 100;
  }

  return result;
}
```

The test code becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string myString = "abcde";
  std::cout << mysteryFunction(myString) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The program prints: `1413121110`

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give this a go and let you know.

Comment: It works perfectly but I'm having some problems incorporating it into my program, I've given details in my question, would you be able to give me a hand? Thanks again, it's fine if not

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest the following solutions.

You could use standard algorithm `std::accumulate` declared in header `<numeric>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>


int main() 
{
    unsigned int a[] = { 10, 11, 12, 13 };

    unsigned long long i = 1;

    unsigned long long s = 
        std::accumulate( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), 0ull,
            [&]( unsigned long long acc, unsigned int x )
            { 
                return ( acc += x * i, i *= 100, acc );
            } );

    std::cout << "s = " << s << std::endl;          

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
s = 13121110
```

The same can be done with using the range based for statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>


int main() 
{
    unsigned int a[] = { 10, 11, 12, 13 };

    unsigned long long i = 1;

    unsigned long long s = 0; 

    for ( unsigned int x : a )
    { 
        s += x * i; i *= 100;
    } 

    std::cout << "s = " << s << std::endl;          

    return 0;
}
```

You could also write a separate function

```
unsigned long long mysteryFunction( const unsigned int a[], size_t n )
{
   unsigned long long s = 0;
   unsigned long long i = 1;

   for ( size_t k = 0; k < n; k++ )
   {
      s += a[k] * i; i *= 100;
   }

   return s;
}
```

Also think about using `std::string` instead of integral numbers to keep an encrypted result.

Answer (score 0):

As [benedek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3347292/benedek) mentioned, here's an implementation using dynamic arrays via std::vector.

```
unsigned mystery(std::vector<unsigned> vect)
{
    unsigned result = 0;
    unsigned factor = 1;

    for (auto& item : vect)
    {
        result += factor * item;
        factor *= 100;
    }

    return result;
}

void main(void)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> ar;
    ar.push_back(10);
    ar.push_back(11);
    ar.push_back(12);
    ar.push_back(13);

    std::cout << mystery(ar);
}
```